# Incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf' using float constants and variables

Tags: c, variables, floating-point, constants

I'm trying to write a simple C program to simulate a shopping experience using fixed constants for price, then asking the user to input an amount they would like to purchase. Then multiplying the amount and the price to get them a total cost.

```
#define TSHIRT   18.95f
//TSHIRT is a constant float for a fixed price on the cost of a t-shirt

int main(void) {
  float numberOfShirts;
  printf("How many T-Shirts would you like?");
  fflush( stdout);
  scanf("%f", &numberOfShirts);
  printf("You will receive %f shirt(s)", numberOfShirts);
  fflush( stdout);

  //This gets the user's amount of shirts they'd like to buy

  float totalCost = (numberOfShirts * TSHIRT);  //Edit: float totalCostadded
  printf("%f", totalCost);

  //this is supposed to be the total cost (amount * price) and print it, 
  //but I get an error -- "incompatible type for argument 1 of 'printf ".
```

How can I fix it or get the correct type to make it work?

Comment: `totalCost` declaration is not posted.  Problem likes in its declaration.  Try `double totalCost = (numberOfShirts * TSHIRT);`

Comment: Also, please read [MCVE]

Comment: Why do you need a `float` for the number of shirts? Will someone buy half a shirt?

Comment: I'll take mine sleeveless, @WeatherVane.  I guess that's about 0.6 shirts.  :)

Comment: Please add a newline `\n` at the end of each `printf` format, then you don't need to keep flushing the output.

Comment: @Weather Vane Is `'\n'` _specified_ to flush the output?  `fflush(stdout);` seems more portable and certain.  Of course, using `'\n'` changes the layout the user sees.

Comment: @chux I don't see many coders omitting the `newline`, which is not supplied by `fflush`.

Comment: BTW my 4 shirts have cost me 75.800003

Comment: `argument 1 of 'printf'` is `const char *`.  I guess to be different from the actual code.

Comment: @Weather Vane Omitting the newline allows the prompt and input to appears on the same line.  Using `'\n'`  changes the user experience.  What OP did was fine and recommend practice to use `fflush(stdout)` when the prompt might lack a final `'\n'`.

Comment: Changing code after getting answer --> DV as it makes the answer inconsistent with the original post.  Suggest reverting the edit.

Comment: @chux sure I understand that for an input to be on the same line as its prompt, but OP should have put `fflush` after the last `printf` statement. Or a `\n`.

Comment: @Benjamin Dare Edwards: The code, in its current form, does not contain any problems with `printf` arguments. It does not produce the diagnostic message you quoted. So, what is your question about?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define "totalCost". Make sure that is a float too. BTW, what you're doing is a bit risky, catching a float in your scanf, if the user accidently enters a letter, your program will crash. Better is to receive a string from scanf and then check its contents and cast it to float, or report an error to the user.

Comment: The program is not certain to crash if the user provides bad input.  Certainly `scanf()` will not crash, but it will not set the value of `numberOfShirts`, either.  That variable is not initialized, so subsequently reading its value would invoke undefined behavior.  More likely than not that would manifest as strange output.

Comment: Note that the type `float` was added (by the OP) to the question after this answer was posted.  However, it appears not to fix the trouble, which is about the type of argument 1, the format string, to the `printf()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You've got various bugs in your code: you didn't declare the variable `totalCost`, declaring it as `float` fixes your type problem.
You also needed to include `stdio.h` and were missing a closing brace.
This version works for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define TSHIRT   18.95f
//TSHIRT is a constant float for a fixed price on the cost of a t-shirt

int main(void) {
    float numberOfShirts;
    printf("How many T-Shirts would you like?");
    fflush( stdout );
    scanf("%f", &numberOfShirts);
    printf("You will receive %f shirt(s)",numberOfShirts);
    fflush( stdout );

    //This gets the user's amount of shirts they'd like to buy

    float totalCost = (numberOfShirts * TSHIRT);
    printf("%f", totalCost);
}
```

Comment: Money and binary float-point has _many_ issues.  IMO, using `float` over `double` makes things worse.

Comment: You may be right. However, it seems that this example is one of OPs first C programs and the question is rather about the general structure and basic types of the C programming language than the problems that arise with modelling money as floating point numbers.

Comment: By using `18.95f`, `float totalCost` and `printf("%f", totalCost);` now one can explain to a learner why 1 shirt result in `18.950001` rather than `18.95`.  Had code used `double`, that issue could be saved for a later day.

Comment: Then again, money has a precision of 10e-2. Even `float` is overkill for that, but `double` is worse in that regard.

Comment: I understand I didn't use <stdio.h> and forgot initializing totalCost, my issue was the Incompatible type for argument 1 as indicated in the post. I just posted the code for a look at what I was doing. I just want to know how to get past this argument 1 for incompatible type.

Comment: @BenjaminDareEdwards for me the incompatible type issue is fixed by declaring the `totalCost` variable. `gcc` does not complain about this, even with all warnings enabled (`-Wall`). And it shouldn't because now you're just multiplying `float` values. Which compiler are you using?